# Dynamically add and delete Data Validation in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vsto, add-in, office-interop

I'm trying to add and delete Data Validation (as well as the inCellDropdown) to a `Range` of cells. It's working OK for the first time I run it. But I always get an error on subsequent executions.

The error I'm getting is "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

This is the code:

```
If type = "a1" Then
  Try
    Me.Range("A1:A20").Validation.Delete()
    Me.Range("A1:A20").Validation.Add(Type:=Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList, _
                    AlertStyle:=Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, _
                    [Operator]:=Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, _
                    Formula1:="=rangedname1")
  Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
  End Try
ElseIf type = "b2" Then
  Try
    Me.Range("A1:A20").Validation.Delete()
    Me.Range("A1:A20").Validation.Add(Type:=Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList, _
                    AlertStyle:=Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, _
                    [Operator]:=Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, _
                    Formula1:="=rangedname2")
  Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
  End Try
EndIf
```

Has anyone dealt with this problem before?

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Is this code running within a loop of some sort?  This error tends to occur because of the start index of 0 in most datatypes, but Excel starts indexing at 1.

Comment: @KevinPope possible, the code is quite complicated. thanks for the info

Comment: I had such problems. My first question is what really fails: delete or add? In my case it showed the same HRESULT when I tried to add a validation 2nd time. I would advise to keep Delete and Add in the different Try-Catch: who knows what may happen :)